# how to set ansi_warnings and ansi_padding off globally in sql server settings?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server 2017, at database level or sql serer level we can set ansi_warnings and Ansi_Padding off?  why because, data loaded from Input file having space append in the column in the sql table.  we need to restrict the space appended in the column. So, we can use ansi_padding off to resolve this issue. Before that i  have to know any other solution is there to change in the settings

Comment: Since many newer features of SQL Server only work with `ansi_padding` set to `on`, it would be better to spend time properly fixing the code that's currently "fixed" by turning the settings off.

Comment: Nor can you set these values "globally" since, as the documentation states, some client libraries set these values themselves and applications are also free to set them anyway they want.

Comment: I think this option only changes at the connection level. So you need to set this option in your connection. Such as you can change this option in SSMS under the Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->ANSI. On the other hand, I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever